# How can I pass a variable to a function without continuing with the original function it was called from in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am not an expert when it comes to Python and I am trying to put several functions together to do the following:

- Ask for a name, if it exists, ask for a password and if it is correct, provide access
- If the name is incorrect, ask the user to either change it or register
- When registering, I want to call another function to check the validity of the password (Password Checker) and then jump back to the rest of the userRegistration function, if the password is strong enough.

However, even when I provide a new password that is too short or long, it will jump back into the original function and execute the rest of the code. I know that the code is not yet finished, but I know that I am not doing it correctly. Any advice, please? Also, when it comes to the final failed attempt for providing the password/username and I want the application to say "Too many attempts", where would be the best place to put it?

The rest of the code pretty much works as expected under ideal conditions (hashing, OTP, SQL, ...)

Here is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import pyotp
import sys
from password_validator import PasswordValidator


connection = sqlite3.connect("localDB.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE passwords")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE passwords (name, password)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO passwords VALUES ('Tomas','password123')")


def OTP():
    totp = pyotp.TOTP('base32secret3232')
    print("This is your one-time passcode: ")
    print(totp.now())
    userOTP = input("Please provided your passcode: ")
    otpass = totp.verify(userOTP)
    if otpass == True:
        print("You are now logged in")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Access Forbidden")
        sys.exit()



def correctUsername(username):
    print("Account found, please provide your password: ")
    retry = 0
    while retry<3:
        userPassword = input()
        cursor.execute('SELECT password FROM passwords WHERE name=?', [username])
        match = cursor.fetchone()
        dbPassword = match[0]
        # print(dbPassword)
        hashedCorrectPassword = hashlib.sha256(str(dbPassword).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        hashedInputPassword = hashlib.sha256(str(userPassword).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        #print(hashedCorrectPassword)
        #print(hashedInputPassword)

        try:
            if hashedInputPassword == hashedCorrectPassword:
                print("That's correct, welcome.")
                OTP()

            else:
                print("That's incorrect, please try again.")
                retry += 1
                continue


        except:
            break
        print("Maximum tries exceeded")

def passwordValidator(registrationPassword):
    schema = PasswordValidator()
    schema.min(8)
    schema.max(15)
    schema.has().uppercase()
    schema.has().lowercase()

    validatePassword = schema.validate(registrationPassword)
    if validatePassword == True:


        print("Good password")

    else:

        print("Try again - not strong enough")





def userRegistration():
    compliance = bool
    print("Register here")
    registrationName = input("What is your name?")
    print("Your name is ", registrationName)
    registrationPassword = input("What is your password?")
    passwordValidator(registrationPassword)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO passwords VALUES (?,?)",(registrationName, registrationPassword))
    print("User successfully registered, please login with your new details: ")
    passwordDatabase()



def passwordDatabase():
    print("Please enter your username: ")

    retry = 0
    while retry<3:
        try:
            username = input()
            if username == "YES":
                userRegistration()
            else:

                cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM passwords WHERE name=?', [username])
                match = cursor.fetchone()
                if match is None:
                    print("No account found, please try again, or type YES for registration")
                    retry += 1
                    continue


                else:
                  correctUsername(username)
                  break

        except:
            break
        print("Maximum tries exceeded.")
```

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the code starts with the passwordDatabase function, which is called from the main function.

Comment: You could just loop inside the validation function until the password validates, or return some value from the function to tell the calling function if the validation failed.

Comment: As asked, this question seems to need more focus; but I have plans to work on a canonical target to explain the general idea with a simple, artificial example, so I'm not casting that close vote in case I can make it a duplicate later.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "However, even when I provide a new password that is too short or long, it will jump back into the original function and execute the rest of the code. I know that the code is not yet finished, but I know that I am not doing it correctly. Any advice, please?" It's hard to understand which part of the code you mean here, and "any advice, please" is [not an answerable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Now that I've tried to read the question some more, it doesn't match the pattern that I thought it did, and it seems to be just generally confused, so my canonical wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make `passwordValidator` both ask for and return the password. The key step here though is to put this asking process in a loop. Something like this

```
def passwordValidator():
    while True:
        valid_password = True
        password = input("What is your password?")
        #
        #
        # validation steps here, if it is invalid, set valid_password to False
        if valid_password:
            return password
```

If an invalid password is entered, the `while` loop will continue and the user will be prompted again to input a password.

Then you can do

```
def userRegistration():
    compliance = bool
    print("Register here")
    registrationName = input("What is your name?")
    print("Your name is ", registrationName)
    registrationPassword = passwordValidator(registrationPassword)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO passwords VALUES (?,?)",(registrationName, registrationPassword))
    print("User successfully registered, please login with your new details: ")
    passwordDatabase()
```